# mysql 5.7.10 create user issues

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysqladmin

Installed latest mysql version 5.7.10 .  When I tried to create new users it's giving me error. Tried different ways  provided in the mysql documents. but it's still giving me  error

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'password_last_changed' in 'mysql.user'
```

Could anyone help me out regarding this .Thanks.

Comment: Did u restart mysql?

Comment: Was this an upgrade from a previous version?  Also, *"Tried different ways provided in the mysql documents"* would be more helpful if you explained what you are talking about.

Comment: In MYSQL 5.7 the user changed a bit : _MySQL now enables database administrators to establish a policy for automatic password expiration: Any user who connects to the server using an account for which the password is past its permitted lifetime must change the password._ For more information [See this page in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-nutshell.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info.  Ran mysql_upgrade , it fixed the tables and now create user is working now.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for the info. Ran mysql_upgrade , it fixed the tables and now create user is working now.